# Borderlands 2 crashing on startup

Tags: technical-issues, borderlands-2

I've been experiencing a crash on startup with my copy of Borderlands 2 through Steam. It all started when I had to forcibly restart my computer while Borderlands 2 was open (note: the restart was required by a non-game related issue).

When attempting to launch the game again, I got a fatal error with a Windows AppCrash message and a stack trace in the image below.  I've also got some memory dump files I can post if someone thinks they'd be useful.

- Windows 7 x64
- Sandy Bridge 2500K
- 2GB Radeon 6950

**Things I've Tried**

- Verifying Borderlands 2's cache
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Borderlands 2
- Uninstalling Borderlands 2, clearing all registry entries containing `Borderlands`, deleting `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Borderlands 2`, uninstalling Steam, reinstalling Steam, reinstalling borderlands.
- Check all audio drivers for updates
- Uninstall and reinstall all audio device drivers

At this point, I'm worried my only course of action will be to reinstall Windows, which I'm not incredibly keen on.  I've also emailed 2K and Gearbox support, but in the meantime I'm hoping someone has seen this same problem and found a less drastic solution than reinstalling Windows.

[image: AK::SoundEngine::StopOutputCapture() AK::MemoryMgr::GetPoolName() AK::MemoryMgr::SetMonitoring() CreateAudioInputSourceParams() BaseThreadInitThunk() RtInitializeExceptionChain() (filename not found)]

Comment: Probably one of the better technical support questions I've seen!

Comment: Looking at the stack trace its having its issue when doing stuff with sound.  Maybe try reinstalling your audio drivers or tweaking the settings in Windows (which version of windows are you running?)

Comment: @JamesJohnson Thanks for reminding me. I'm running Win 7 x64

Comment: @Fluttershy Thanks! I doubt that anyone other 2K or Gearbox support can really help me, but I figured I'd take a shot and see if anyone has seen the same thing or can help me investigate further. Worst case, once I hear back from 2K or Gearbox and get it resolved, I figure I can throw up an answer in case anyone else sees it

Comment: I was going to say force an update on your Borderlands 2 files, but it seems you've done that and more already.  I agree that it definitely looks to be an issue with audio, but more specifically with your microphone.  Try disabling all audio input sources.

Comment: Maybe it's not the installation that has gone bad, but your configuration is corrupt? Try moving all config files out of their normal locations (as backup) and try running again.  i.e., the files in `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Borderlands 2`.

Comment: @JeffMercado Thanks for the suggestion. I forgot to mention that I've also deleted that entire folder multiple occasions :/

Comment: @MBraedley Disabled all my audio sources without any difference. The stacktrace still referenced `CreateAudioInputSourceParams()`. How irritating. Thanks for the thought, though

Comment: @DaveMcClelland: Yeah, it was worth a shot.  It looks like you're going to be waiting on Gearbox and/or 2k support.

Comment: @DaveMcClelland Do you experience the crashes after the "Preparing to Launch" window? If you do, try this: Create a .txt file in notepad and write the numbers '49520' without the ' '. Save it as 'steam_appid.txt' and save it in your Steam directory 'Steam\steamapps\common\Borderlands 2\Binaries\Win32' and run Borderlands2.exe as admin. ([Source](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Borderlands_2#Create_steam_appid.txt))

Comment: I'm going to guess bad memory stick due to the loops in the memory manager. Try due memory stress and/or benchmarking tests, reseating, swapping memory slots and/or removing one, trying different memory sticks. What was the "non-game related issue" that forced the first restart? Was it a hardware exception? Do you have problems with any other games? Any other UT engine games? Also, have you tried clearing CMOS and removing all power from the device? (Not sure if that still helps these days, but years ago that would help memory issues.)

Comment: @Mufasa Every so often (maybe once a month), my keyboard will completely stop responding, and all input will stop. My mouse still works, but when I'm in game I'm usually unable to do anything other than look around. When I can't exit things cleanly (usually because I can't press escape), I'll just hard reboot my computer. It's an ugly solution, but it's such an infrequent and inconsistent problem I haven't had the motivation to debug it further. The keyboard is a Microsoft Ergonomic 4000, if that's helpful.

Comment: @galacticninja Thanks for the link. It seemed promising as the crash is after "preparing to launch," although it happens during the first intro video (I believe it's 2K's). If I get a chance tonight I'll try to record the crash

Comment: @DaveMcClelland: Regarding keyboard, USB sometimes freaks out. Have your tried unplugging the keyboard and plugging it back in, or into a different USB port? Sometimes that helps when only the keyboard stops working.

Comment: This might be related to the issues the game has been having recently. Though I'm not sure if http://www.xbox360achievements.org/news/news-13228-Borderlands-2-Afflicted-by-Game-Breaking-Bug--Gearbox-Quiet-on-Solution.html is specific to Xbox or PC too? But that link and the referenced forums might be helpful.

Comment: @Mufasa I'll try changing USB ports and unplugging the keyboard the next time it fails. I'm inclined to believe this is a more isolated problem, as it had been working fine until I rebooted and then immediately started crashing after I rebooted (I tried to start playing right after rebooting).

Comment: Thanks to all who helped out, I finally [found the answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/90062/4775)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After nearly giving up, I found the answer on [Gearbox's forums](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=172593).

From the post:

- Delete Borderlands 2 in Documents/My Games (not WillowEngine.ini)
- Stop cloud storage in Borderlands 2 Steam properties
- Verify cache in properties
- [Activate the nologo option](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showpost.php?p=2975353&postcount=4) :
- Launch the game and turn off automatic detection in launcher's config (put all options in off or lowest possible)
- If the game start, it will create a new profile.bin... Quit the game and put your saves (not the corrupted profile) in the correct folder. Restart the game.

It does seem that this causes the [well](http://www.destructoid.com/borderlands-2-bug-resets-badass-rank-gearbox-fixing-it-235623.phtml) [known](http://www.gameinformer.com/b/news/archive/2012/10/09/badass-rank-reset-bug-reappears-with-new-borderlands-2-dlc.aspx) issue that causes badass rank to get reset, however. The Gearbox forum post listed above provides information on how to manipulate it using Cheat Engine, but I'm personally going to wait and hope for them to release a fix that recalculates it automatically.

Comment: Oh right, the cloud... I knew the data was corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting exactly the same problem and the way to fix it is to restore your `profile.bin` file in your saved game folder to an earlier version. `C:\Users\%userprofile%\Documents\My Games\Borderlands 2\WillowGame\SaveData\76561197969377489`

I did that and it fixed my game.